# Commit updated Proguard mapping during Maven 3 release

Tags: android, maven-3, proguard

I use Maven 3 to manage the build and release cycle of my Android application. During a release the application source is obfuscated using the Proguard maven plugin. Ideally I'd like the updated Proguard obfuscation mapping to be committed into the git repository during the release process. I currently attach the mapping to the artifacts pushed to the release repository but I'd like to keep the mapping in git if possible.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to do to pass configuration in so the solution from @khmarbaise will not suffice. I would recomment using the maven-scm plugin in a release profile attached immediately after the proguard mapping is created.

You will want to add the mapping file:
http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/add-mojo.html

and then check it in
http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html

Perhaps something like:

```
<profiles>

  <profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>performRelease</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
    </activation>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
          ...
          <configuration>
            ... add your scm setup here ...
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>addMap</id>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>commitMap</id>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>checkin</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a goal before the commit happens via the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/run-goals-before-commit.html) as described in the documentation.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <preparationGoals>clean verify</preparationGoals>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```